# CSS - Position flexbox dropdown above content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the navigation bar for my personal site. I'm using flexbox because it's the only (pure CSS) solution I've found so far where the dropdown plays nicely with the link background color.

I'm trying to position the dropdown so that it floats over the content when opened. I tried setting the main nav `li` elements to have `position: relative,` then setting `position: absolute` and `z-index: 1` for `.dropdown ul` , which technically works, but it breaks the grey background color for the link. I also tried using blocks, but it still looks bad either way. Does anyone know a pure CSS solution for this?

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: white;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex: auto;
}

/*** NAV ***/
.navbar {
 font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
 font-size: 16pt;
}

.navbar ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0;
 margin: 0 0;
}

.navbar a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.navbar ul li {
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

.navbar li:hover {
 background-color: grey;
 transition: ease-in-out .25s;
}

.dropdown ul {
 margin: 0;
 display: none;
}

.dropdown ul li {
 padding: 2px 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover ul, .dropdown ul:hover {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

/*** CONTENT ***/
.content {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-left: 0;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="author" content="Ariel Mordoch">
 <meta name="description" content="The personal website of Ariel Mordoch.">
 <title>Ariel Mordoch</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="navbar"> 
   <nav>
    <ul class="container">
     <li><a href="index.html">ariel mordoch</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">resume</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
     
     <li class="dropdown">drop
       <ul class="container">
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 
 <main>
  <div class="content">
   <p>placeholder</p>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eq6o3yp5/8/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37332329/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you position it as absolute, the relative element do not get 'stretched' or resized, and so, that is why the background of the relative element do not reflect on the absolute positioned element.

Position it as absolute and give it a `width`, perhaps a `min-width`... and set a desired `background-color` or set it `background-color: inherit;`

```
.dropdown:hover ul, .dropdown ul:hover {
    ...
    background-color: grey;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: white;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex: auto;
}

/*** NAV ***/
.navbar {
 font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
 font-size: 16pt;
}

.navbar ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0;
 margin: 0 0;
}

.navbar a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.navbar ul li {
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

.navbar li:hover {
 background-color: grey;
 transition: ease-in-out .25s;
}

.dropdown ul {
 margin: 0;
 display: none;
}

.dropdown ul li {
 padding: 2px 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover ul, .dropdown ul:hover {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

/*** CONTENT ***/
.content {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-left: 0;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="author" content="Ariel Mordoch">
 <meta name="description" content="The personal website of Ariel Mordoch.">
 <title>Ariel Mordoch</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="navbar"> 
   <nav>
    <ul class="container">
     <li><a href="index.html">ariel mordoch</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">resume</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
     
     <li class="dropdown">drop
       <ul class="container">
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 
 <main>
  <div class="content">
   <p>placeholder</p>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```